# File System vs. Path module in Node.js

Tags: node.js, file-io, path, node-modules

What are the purposes and differences between these two modules in Node.js? Does one depend on the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What are the purposes and differences between these two modules in
>   Node.js?

The `fs` module is for actually operating on files, directories and volumes (assuming you have already built an appropriate path for the target).  The `path` module is for manipulating paths which you may then use with the `fs` module since many `fs` methods accept a path as an argument.

The `fs` module contains functions for manipulating files such as:

```
fs.readFile()
fs.mkdir()
fs.open()
fs.stat()
```

etc...

The `path` module contains functions for manipulating file paths such as:

```
path.join()
path.normalize()
path.extname()
path.parse()
```

You can read the entire list of functions in each module yourself:

[fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

[path module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html)

The descriptions should be pretty obvious what they do.

> Does one depend on the other?

Probably not.  The `fs` module assumes you already have a valid path that can be passed right on through to the OS.  The `path` module only builds or parses paths, it doesn't actually do operations on files.

It would be very common to use the two together.  For example, you might use the `path` module to construct a path which you then pass to an `fs` module function.

Answer (score 2):

Path module is actually used to construct a valid path from several chunks which never validates in your file system or you can say drives/volumes and gives you an absolute path in string form. Let say, you have drive, the relative path of a file to that particular drive, filename, and extension. In that case, you can construct a valid filename by combining it.

FS module meant to manipulate the filesystem. Like creating a directory, file, renaming etc...